# combining columns so words become column value v column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am wanting to get df1 to combine `AA, AB and v` which is added through `df3["C"] = "v"`.

df1

```
    AA   AB        AC      AD     AE
0  fry  pan  calendar  cakery  chock
1    a  pan  calendar  cakery  chock
2  fry  pan  calendar  cakery  chock
3    a  pan  calendar  cakery  chock
```

Wanting for df3:

```
    AA   AB        AC      AD     AE   AF
0  fry  pan  calendar  cakery  chock   fry v pan
1    a  pan  calendar  cakery  chock   a v pan
2  fry  pav  calendar  cakery  chock   fry v pav
3    a  pan  calendar  cakery  chock   a v pab
```

KeyError:

```
('C', 'occurred at index 0')
```

In:

```
df3["C"] = np.nan
df3["C"] = "v"
AAAAAH = df1['combined']=df1.apply(lambda x:'%s_%s_%s' % (x['AA'],x['C'],x['AB']),axis=1)
df3['AB']=AAAAAH
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine columns without `apply`:

```
df['new'] = df['AA'] + ' v ' + df['AB']
print (df)

    AA   AB        AC      AD     AE        new
0  fry  pan  calendar  cakery  chock  fry v pan
1    a  pan  calendar  cakery  chock    a v pan
2  fry  pan  calendar  cakery  chock  fry v pan
3    a  pan  calendar  cakery  chock    a v pan
```

Or if need assign to `AB` column:

```
df['AB'] = df['AA'] + ' v ' + df['AB']
print (df)
    AA         AB        AC      AD     AE
0  fry  fry v pan  calendar  cakery  chock
1    a    a v pan  calendar  cakery  chock
2  fry  fry v pan  calendar  cakery  chock
3    a    a v pan  calendar  cakery  chock
```